# ModRewrite: Redirect anything but Root "/"?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do something incredibly simple: If the user requests the home page, http://www.OurSite.com/, then stop all rules and serve the file normally. If anything else in the world is requested, silently redirect to a php script.

I'm using this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /000_ROUTE.php [L]
```

It seems that my condition is being ignored and the home page is redirecting too.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Turn on rewrite debugging and paste results if the answer isn't obvious from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rule is used in a .htaccess file, use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/000_ROUTE.php$
RewriteRule . /000_ROUTE.php [L]
```

If it's in your VirtualHost-block or main config file instead, use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/000_ROUTE.php$
RewriteRule /. /000_ROUTE.php [L]
```

(the only difference is the leading slash on the RewriteRule).

The first thing Apache httpd does before evaluating the RewriteConds is to evaluate the RewriteRule. Putting the condition into the Rule (and in this case the condition is that there is at least one character after the slash) saves Apache having to evaluate the RewriteCond entirely for requests at "/". The RewriteCond ensures that you don't end up in a loop of rewrites -- after all, 000_ROUTE.php is not "/", either.)

Depending on how often that rule will get hit (i.e. if you expect it to get hit a lot and thus separating out a RewriteCond is just going to add overhead), you could also condense it into

```
RewriteRule ^(?!000_ROUTE.php). /000_ROUTE.php [R,L]
```

for .htaccess or -contexts

```
RewriteRule ^/(?!000_ROUTE.php). /000_ROUTE.php [R,L]
```

for  or server-contexts.